# Javascript: is parenthesis required with new keyword to create a new instance

Tags: javascript, new-operator

So I see many code where an instance is created without the parenthesis. for e.g.

`var o = new f`

[image: Instance without parenthesis - Chrome console]

Does it differ in any way to the usual way of creating instances ie. with parenthesis other than the fact that parenthesis allows to pass arguments.

`var o = new f()`

Also, is the `new` keyword that executes the function (without parenthesis) as mentioned in this answer [What-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3658673/8069961), particularly this line:

> It executes the constructor function, using the newly created object whenever this is mentioned.

Thanks